# homotopy type of the group of homeomorphisms of circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the group of homeomorphisms of $S^1$. What is the homotopy type of this group w.r.t compact open topology ?

I know there are homeomorphisms such as rotation; another type is fix any line through origin and then flip the upper half of the line to lower half and vice versa.  This map will have two fixed points.

So what are the other types of homeomorphisms?

Comment: (Just to be clear: you're not requiring that the homeomorphisms $S^1 \to S^1$ be themselves group homomorphisms? If you did require that, the answer's easy: it's $\mathbb{Z}_2$.)

Comment: There is a lot known. Do you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: I have edited my question @mike miller

Comment: The examples you describe are not only homeomorphisms of $S^1$, but distance-preserving (rotation and reflection).  Perhaps your interest lies in characterizing how many fixed points a homeomorphism can have (or in the narrower problem of how many fixed points a distance-preserving map on the circle can have).  The phrase "homotopy type of the group of homeomorphisms" seems unclear, although it suggests the problem of when two homeomorphisms are homotopic.

Comment: I want to know what are the other type of homeomorphism other than this.consider the group of homeomorphism and give it compact open topology .then what will be the homotopy type of this space.@hardmath